# react js , AR VR, 3d modeling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

Integrating AR (Augmented Reality) and VR (Virtual Reality) with 3D modeling in React.js involves leveraging various libraries and frameworks to create immersive experiences. Firstly, consider using libraries like A-Frame, React 360, or Three.js to render 3D models

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.